# statement not compiling

Tags: java

I have a method from decompiled code that i am trying to run and understand.
    The 5 line does not compile and i get an error saying
    incompatible types required: java util.Hashmap found: java.lang.String.

```
private void resetFieldModel(HashMap<String, Integer> to_use_map)
{
    this.current_field_model.removeAllElements();
    Set temp_set = to_use_map.keySet();

    for (String s : temp_set)
    {
        this.current_field_model.addElement(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must iterate through the `temp_set` which must of `Set<String>` type(in your code). The idea is that each element in `temp_set` is of type `String`

Answer (score 5):

You need to type-parameterize the `temp_set`.

```
Set<String> temp_set = to_use_map.keySet();
```

#### See also:

- [Java Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)